# Panic when can't create a directory

Tags: rust

I'm writing a Rust program which will create a directory based on user input. I would like to know how to `panic` with my own text when `error` occurs, like `Permission Error` etc...

```rust
fn create_dir(path: &String) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    std::fs::create_dir_all(path)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

This will do nothing when `error` occcurs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this case, the simplest way is to use [`unwrap_or_else()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap_or_else):

```rust
fn create_dir(path: &str) {
    std::fs::create_dir_all(path)
        .unwrap_or_else(|e| panic!("Error creating dir: {}", e));
}
```

Note that I also changed the argument type, for the reasons described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o).

---

However, it would be more idiomatic to accept a `&Path` or `AsRef<Path>`.

```rust
use std::fs;
use std::path::Path;

fn create_dir<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) {
    fs::create_dir_all(path)
        .unwrap_or_else(|e| panic!("Error creating dir: {}", e));
}
```

Comment: It is probably because you have the permisions to create a directory. Try and example like - ```std::fs::create_dir_all("/some/dir/")
        .unwrap_or_else(|e| panic!("Error creating dir: {}", e));```
in the rust playground and it fails with a permission denied eror.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this worked! May I ask you, what that `|e| ` means?

Comment: @MarcelKopera `|e| panic!("Error creating dir: {}", e)` is a closure, where `e` is the error value. Thereby if `create_dir_all()` returns an `Err` then the closure is called resulting in the `panic!`